# replace strings with variables

Tags: php, string, variables, replace

```
$var1 = 'abc';
$var2 = '123';
```

How can I replace `%var1` and `%var2%` from a string like this:

```
aaaaaaaa%var1%bbbbbbbbb%var2%ffffffff
```

with the value of `$var1` and `$var2` ?

Comment: whaaaaaaat -2 ?? fuuuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming >= PHP 5.3...

```
preg_replace_callback('%(\w+?)%', function($matches) use ($var1, $var2) {
   return $$matches[1][0];
}, $str);
```

As you can see, you need to pass a reference to each of the outer variables to the closure.

You are probably better constructing an array with the replacement variables, and just passing that array in and then subscripting it...

```
preg_replace_callback('%(\w+?)%', function($matches) use ($vars) {
   return isset($vars[$matches[1][0]]) ? $vars[$matches[1][0]] : $matches[0][0];
}, $str);
```

I haven't got a chance to test this code right now, but I believe the general principle is sound :)

Comment: can you post a example of how would I pass the array? do I replace the function() with it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$var1 = 'abc';
$var2 = '123';
$subject = 'aaaaaaaa%var1%bbbbbbbbb%var2%ffffffff';

echo str_replace(array('%var1%', '%var2%'), array($var1, $var2), $subject);

// output: aaaaaaaaabcbbbbbbbbb123ffffffff
```

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to take the string literal

`'aaaaaaaa%var1%bbbbbbbbb%var2%ffffffff'` and replace the substrings `var1` and `var2` with `'abc'` and `'123'`, respectively, right?  In that case, [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) should do the trick.